# Can not write on a table in redshift

Tags: python, amazon-redshift, airflow

I am trying to copy a file from `S3` to `redshift` table but I am unable to do so. However, I can read from the table so I know that my connection is okay.
Please help me to figure out the problem.

```
def upload_redshift():
    conn_string = passd.redshift_login['login'] //the connection string containing dbname, username etc.
    con = psycopg2.connect(conn_string);
    sql = """FROM 's3://datawarehouse/my_S3_file' credentials 'aws_access_key_id=***;aws_secret_access_key=***' csv ; ;"""
    try:
        con = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
        logging.info("Connection Successful!")
    except:
        raise ValueError("Unable to connect to Redshift")

    cur = con.cursor()
    try:
        cur.execute(sql)

        logging.info("  Copy to redshift executed successfully")
    except:
        raise ValueError("Failed to execute copy command")
    con.close()
```

I am getting `Copy to redshift executed successfully` message but nothing is happening in my table.

Comment: you need to provide more info. try the copy command directly (not through python) - did that work? and - where is your "copy" command word? also - provide your output from cur.execute e.g. print(cur.execute(sql))

Comment: okay, so everything works just as fine in sqlworkbench, i can crete table run copy command etc from workbench, but i can only read data from airflow

Answer (score 1):

Try the following,

```
sql = "copy table_name FROM 's3://datawarehouse/my_S3_file' credentials 'aws_access_key_id=***;aws_secret_access_key=***' csv ;"
```

Also, try creating the connection under "connections tab" and use PostgresHook with aws_access_key_id and key as variables, something like below which enables to store the details encrypted within airflow,

```
pg_db = PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id='<<connection_id>>')
src_conn = pg_db.get_conn()
src_cursor = src_conn.cursor()
src_cursor.execute(sql)
src_cursor.commit()
src_cursor.close()
```

Also, you can use s3_to_redshift_operator operator and execute it as a task,

```
from airflow.operators.s3_to_redshift_operator import S3ToRedshiftTransfer

T1 = S3ToRedshiftTransfer(
        schema = ‘’,
        table = ‘’,
        s3_bucket=‘’,
        s3_key=‘’,
        redshift_conn_id=‘’, #reference to a specific redshift database
        aws_conn_id=‘’, #reference to a specific S3 connection
    )
```

Comment: tried that didnt work, i also noticed that i cannot do any write work on the database for example making tables etc, however read works just as fine

Comment: Did you check DB access levels for the credentials you are using?

Comment: Try executing it as a task since in airflow you have s3_to_redshift_operator operator, below is the sample code, I'll edit the answer with the same as well,                       from airflow.operators.s3_to_redshift_operator import S3ToRedshiftTransfer

T1 = S3ToRedshiftTransfer(
  schema = ‘’,
  table = ‘’,
  s3_bucket=‘’,
  s3_key=‘’,
  redshift_conn_id=‘’, #reference to a specific redshift database
  aws_conn_id=‘’, #reference to a specific S3 connection
 )